# Install ClipBucket on XAMPP 1.7.3 give no button for next installation step

Tags: xampp

When installing ClipBucket on XAMPP 1.7.3, I encounter the following screen. I notice that there is no button for me to click to the next step (which is Pre-check) and thus I cannot do anything. Appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on the ClipBucket installation.

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? What operating system? Generally I'd say, try a different browser.

Comment: @slhck, I tried different browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc), different XAMPP version (Version 1.7.3, 1.7.7) but still no result. I do not think that the operating system can play any important roles for this scenario - in my own opinion.

Comment: Well, I've seen some really screwed up web app layouts using Firefox or Chrome on OS X before, whereas the Windows versions seemed to do fine. Might be a weird bug. But if it doesn't depend on the browser in your case, I really don't know.

Comment: @slhck, Interesting enough - never thought that a OS can do such serious impact on the web app layout. Anyway, I will be just on the lookout for a answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

**short_tags need to be 'on' in XAMPP's PHP.ini file.**  Clipbucket is for Linux.  The only way to have a 'real' Clipbucket or such video script is using Linux. Long story.  I am still trying to get Clipbucket to work in Windows and its been weeks now.

Comment: I admire your perseverance for trying to get Clipbucket to work. You can also try the PHPMotion as both PHPMotion and Clipbucket I tried on XAMPP but always fail at the installation part. I read the link (http://forums.clip-bucket.com/showthread.php?676-ClipBucket-Installation-Guide&p=2810#post2810) but it still does not work for ClipBucket. Let me know if it work at your side.